# Symfony2 - Update the result of SQL query using JQuery / AJAX

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'd like to access to a function in my controller from an external javascript file using Jquery. This function is used to run a SQL query so I want to 're-run' this query to update the result in my page without reloading it.

Any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow those steps in order to do it

Add route in routing.xml

```
report_orders_get_ajax:
    path: /admin/report/orders/ajax
    defaults:  { _controller: ApplicationDemoBundle:ApplicationDemo:getAjaxData}
```

In controller it should look like this

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ApplicationDemoController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getAjaxDataAction(Request $request) {
        $result = array('data' => '123', 'valid' => true);

        return new JsonResponse($result);
    }
}
```

Finally in javascript file you can use simple jquery ajax request

```
$.get('{{path('report_orders_get_ajax')}}', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```